# Texas, USA speed ticket as a European citizen, already left the country

Tags: usa, legal, driving, texas

I had an interesting experience in the US while speeding. I'll put the full scenario in quotes, as I'm not sure if the whole story really adds to the question.

We are unsure of what to do with the ticket. The officer didn't explain anything (he was very rude and threatening, as you can read in the scenario), the paper we got says very little other than 'to report to court within 15 days otherwise a warrant for your arrest will be made'. We left the country hours after we got the speeding ticket. What do we do now? We wish to visit the US/Texas again.

And would it be possible for us to fight the ticket? We believe it was unfair and unnecessary.

> We just changed onto a different interstate. Previous interstate was
>   75mph, we couldn't find any signs but people were going faster than
>   75mph so we decided to 'go with the flow' and drive about 74/75. After
>   only minutes on the interstate we got pulled over. The officer came to
>   the car with his gun drawn (yes, really!) yelling at us not to move.
>   He wouldn't let us speak, he wouldn't let us move. He asked questions
>   but didn't let us finish the answers. We made it very clear we were
>   tourists in a rental car, yet he proceeded to ask us if we were
>   Californian citizens (the car had a Cali license) multiple times.
>   After the 3rd time we said we explained where we were from he finally
>   put the gun away. He told us what we did wrong and when we tried to explain we were tourists and were just trying to do the right thing, he told us to stop talking. He told us to report to court within 15 days and
>   when we tried to explain we were leaving the country and didn't know what to do and he told us in a
>   very threatening way we 'better report to court within 15 days or a
>   warrant would be put out'.
>
> This all happened at election night, I hope the officer was just
>   having a bad day and this is NOT a normal experience with the law in
>   the US. I am frankly very scared and do not wish to drive in the US
>   anymore.

Comment: I'd pay the ticket; spend a few bucks calling the ticket office (there should be a phone number on the ticket) and ask how you can pay (money transfer, western union...) it and be done with it.

Comment: @pnuts no dollar amount, the limit was 60 apparently, although we failed to find any signs to prove it was. We drove 74 because we thought the limit was 75, just as the interstate we drove on minutes before.

Comment: @Max so paying the ticket without going to court is an option? Because the paper doesn't make it seem so. We're setting up a skype account so we can call the court tomorrow.

Comment: You usually go to court if you do not pay the ticket (or want to fight the ticket)

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 a scan or photo of the entire ticket you were given may clarify matters here - ensure you blank out personal info.

Comment: @Moo if you want I can post a picture later but it literally only says you need to report to court within 15 days, does this mean it is a 'bigger' offense than just a traffic fine?

Comment: Likely not, but you can call the court and ask. The court clerk isn't out to trip you up and can explain the procedures and options.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 Court for a traffic fine is a standard 'feature' of the US system.  You can can pay up front and not go to court. Go to court and plead no-contest and pay a lesser amount (depending on the court) or go full on not guilty and try to get away with no penalty at all.  It all depends on the chutzpah you have.  I once saw a defendant plead not guilty, give a story that was unprovable and got his case dismissed.

Comment: Also in at least some states, if the officer fails to show up to court for your case, the case is dismissed

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 What are the charge(s) listed on the citation? I know you mentioned speed several times, but is it possible that you were charged with some other moving violation, such as multiple lane changes? (Most states require a specific amount of time be spent signaling in each lane.) It seems very strange for an officer to approach with weapon drawn for a speeding violation, even a significant one, if other traffic laws are observed and you stop immediately upon their approach. As mentioned, a copy of the citation / ticket (personal info removed) could explain a lot.

Comment: Hard for me to believe there is no stated fine you can just pay.

Comment: Quick question as to why he might have drawn the gun - did you try to get out of the car?  That's not uncommon in some European countries.  In the US, it's very unusual and might raise the officer's alert level.

Comment: @Joel we didn't get out of the car or move since the cop approached the car shouting 'don't move

Comment: @CodeShane There is no fine listed. I will post a picture tonight, have not found the time to do so yet.

Comment: "I hope the officer was just having a bad day and this is NOT a normal `xperience with the law in the US` - as  European, I have been stopped twice by police in the USA and would say that you epxeirenced the milder end of the spectrum :-(  I was once once stopped for running a red light ***which did not exist*** and the opening salvo, was don't talk back, or I ***will** put you on the ground.

Comment: Some context for police action: I too have been stopped for speeding in a out of state rental car on the interstate in Texas.  This is precisely what they are looking for, especially if your car appears to be weighed down by a heavy load (in my case it was luggage).  They are trying to catch interstate drug runners who use rental cars to avoid forfeiture laws.

Comment: OP, is there anything useful on the **back** of the ticket, perhaps a phone number and/or schedule of fines?

Comment: What is the charge on the citation? Without this information it is impossible to make any responsible recommendation. The guy had his gun out because you were in a rental car, which means there is no way to know who is in the car.

Comment: Many (perhaps most) traffic offenses are "civil" infractions, but more serious offenses are "criminal". For example, speeding 10 MPH over the limit is likely a "civil" offense. 30 MPH over the limit, or reckless driving or DUI could be a "criminal" offense. If the charge is serious enough, then a court appearance could be mandatory. The "fine" to be paid may be decided by the Judge and may not be known ahead of time. It doesn't sound like the offense was serious in your case, but the officer may have (unreasonably) written the ticket for a higher offense.

Comment: @AllInOne One assumes that drug runners make an effort to obey traffic laws, though I suppose you don't actually have to be speeding for an officer to use it as pretext for a stop?

Comment: The situation couldn't be simpler. (1) you were speeding and you have to pay the ticket.  (2) it is utterly normal that they have to deal with folks from overseas - think how many millions of visitors there are to the US; it's just completely normal.  (3) phone the number on the ticket and pay.  You express that the officer was rude: absolutely nothing, at all, can be done about this unless you wish to raise a civil case. If you do want to do that it couldn't be simpler: phone a solicitor in the area and launch a suit.  There's nothing more to it.  You got a speeding ticket, pay it.

Comment: If, incredibly, you want to try to fight the ticket (and again this is completely normal, it would happen 1000s of times a week in the US), it couldn't be simpler. Google to the first traffic-attorney you see in that area, use a phone to phone them, pay them some money and they'll try to fight the ticket.

Comment: He might've been trying to do you a favor by telling you to stop talking: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8z7NC5sgik  If your story is "we didn't know what the speed limit was", he'd know immediately nothing else you were going to say could possibly improve your situation. But if you foolishly babbled the wrong thing, your situation could definitely get worse.

Comment: Yes, AllInOne is almost certainly correct that they suspected you of drug running. Police most certainly do not normally pull their gun when they pull someone over for speeding in the U.S., nor shout at them to not move, etc. In general, they don't even pull you over for speeding if you're going the same speed as the general flow of traffic, even if that is above the speed limit. The speeding was probably just the excuse they used to stop you.

Comment: Stories like this are enough to put me off travelling to the US entirely.

Comment: @Simba getting pulled over for speeding? You can always just not speed. It's well known that it's against the law in the US and many other countries. Not sure why that seems unusual to you. There are plenty of other (good) reasons to not visit the States, but the fear of getting pulled over for speeding is not one of them.

Comment: @Lilienthal Criminals (especially the ones running the drugs) tend not to be the sharpest knives in the drawer...

Comment: @sgroves - of course I don't go travelling with the intention of breaking the law. But I've heard plenty of stories like this where people have been pulled over without obvious cause (like this story, slightly over the limit but no faster than surrounding traffic), and then having the cop pull a gun on them. That's the bit that really scares me; the cavalier attitude toward guns among American cops, and Americans in general. Where I come from, police generally do not carry guns. Somehow they still manage to enforce the law, and usually without shooting anyone. Yeah, crazy, but true.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48839/discussion-on-question-by-janedoe1337-texas-usa-speed-ticket-as-a-european-citi).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A relevant resource would be

[Texas DMV paying tickets](http://www.dmv.org/tx-texas/paying-traffic-tickets.php) (Disclaimer - this is a 3rd party website and not connected to the government.  We really need the jurisdiction of your court in order to provide an official link.  On the other hand this is a good start)

IMHO paying the ticket will be cheaper than hiring a lawyer to represent you and fight the ticket - especially with you not being in the country let alone the state.  I don't think that they can affect your license/insurance in Europe, on the other hand if they issue a warrant for your arrest it will stick around for a very long time and could cause you a lot of grief in the future if you come back to the US.

In either case it would definitely be worthwhile to call the appropriate court and speak to the Court Clerk and get their opinion on the matter.  I'm not sure if you can get it dismissed that way, but it is worth a try.

But whatever you decide make sure to do it before the court date.

---

Finally as a foreigner living in the US I am always amazed at the capriciousness of the cops pulling people over for speeding as well as 10mph over the limit on a freeway being ignored.

From my point of view if the posted speed limit is 60 and everybody does 75 and the cops don't pull everybody over then the de facto speed limit *is* 75. I just don't have the guts to argue this point in court!

But then every once in a while they do a speeding blitz and start pulling people over for only a few mph over the posted limit.  Then a day later its all back to normal.

Comment: Good answer, but note that link is not an official government website.

Comment: @ZachLipton damn it .. I fell for it.

Comment: If it was issued by the [Highway Patrol](https://www.txdps.state.tx.us/highwaypatrol/citations/), you can search for the jurisdiction.

Comment: Don't be amazed but there are multiple reasons for cops allowing speeds up to 75mph but that's a long discussion to be had another time.

Comment: "in the US there is cutoff point for speeding at 20mph over" - this is wrong. The point at which speeding is automatically reckless driving can be less than 20, or, like in Texas, there might not be a set speed at all. It varies by state, but crucially, "X above the limit" does *not* go the other direction; even going less than the posted limit can be reckless driving.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Point taken

Comment: For an extreme example of what @EsotericScreenName is talking about the cutoff for reckless driving (or something that's a misdemeanor instead of just a citation) is 80 MPH.  This was apparently set when the speed limit was 55, the speed limit has been gradually raised to 75 on some interstates but the big hammer is still set at 80.

Comment: @DanNeely the cutoff for reckless driving cannot be an absolute like 80; there are some highways in Texas that have a speed limit of [80](https://www.google.com/maps/@30.4943274,-97.5828734,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sYuggEFCKSv_ce7z3gYlFJg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) or [even higher](https://www.google.com/maps/@29.837557,-97.7313715,3a,75y,47.1h,88.01t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1syZ6bau7EOoAl_xscp4C-vw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656).

Comment: (1) Do handle this before the court date or the situation gets worse (2) If you use the Texas DMV website (no idea what that is...) contact the court clerk after about a week to be sure that everything is OK. You want to be absolutely sure that this doesn't bite you if you ever come to the US again.

Comment: @DanNeely In TX, all speeding tickets are at least a class C misdemeanor.

Comment: @shoover  *argh*  There needs to be a way to edit comments.  I reordered what I wrote before submitting and managed to omit the relevant jurisdiction, Virginia, from the final version.

Comment: "But then every once in a while they do a speeding blitz and start pulling people over for only a few mph over the posted limit. Then a day later its all back to normal." - that's called **revenue enhancement**.

Comment: @BobJarvis There is a section of I-95 near me that falls inside a particular country for only a few miles.  The State Police are a bit pissed off that the local country cops aggressively police this one small section in order to boost revenue for their otherwise not well off county.

Comment: Just because you're not pulled over for speeding doesn't mean there is no speed limit. It just means there's at the moment no capacity or need to strictly enforce it (maybe the single cop on traffic duty is on another road...).

Comment: Does the section after the separator really add anything to this answer? Besides encouraging discussion in the comments?

Comment: @Lilienthal In other countries the police *will always* pull you over for doing a fraction of an amount over the speed limit and people are conditioned to travel at or below the posted limit.  The bit below the bar is meant to point out how different the US is with regards to speeding.

Comment: @PeterM Well that first statement is simply not true and that summary doesn't match what you're actually saying in your answer which is basically "US cops never enforce speed regulations to the letter except when they do.". That's largely useless for a tourist, especially the OP, and the only take-away I get from those paragraphs is that you're annoyed by what you perceive as inconsistent enforcement of traffic laws based on anecdotal experience. I share that annoyance but it's detracting from your answer.

Comment: Hi @PeterM - "In other countries the police will always pull you over for doing a fraction of an amount over the speed limit"  I'm interested, which country is that?  Maybe Japan?  I don't know of any like that.

Comment: @JoeBlow Try Australia for one with a worse case tolerances of less than 2mph over the limit in Victoria.  Plus on the Melbourne/Sydney freeway you don't just have instantaneous speed cameras, you have average speed cameras that track your speed over extended distances.

Comment: @JoeBlow in the UK, there is a 2mph tolerance, but technically, 1mph over the speed limit and you can be ticketed / pulled over, and enough offences will result in a ban from driving. Here it's taken much more seriously where there is a danger to the public, motorways etc are usually more lax, but some parts have auto speed cameras - priority is on danger of the speeding rather than blanket enforcement of the letter of the law, and people are conditioned to drive at the limt. source: http://www.ukmotorists.com/speed%20enforcement%20policy%20guidelines%20for%20uk%20police%20forces.asp

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48840/discussion-on-answer-by-peter-m-texas-usa-speed-ticket-as-a-european-citizen-a).

Answer (score 33):

I've been a TX resident for more than 10 years. The visit with the cop you had is typical of ALL police. They are always rude- it's the norm for one reason or another, I don't why and I really don't care.

You don't need to worry about anything. Just call the number on the ticket which is the court, and tell them you want to pay over the phone - you'll need a credit card. If you want to fight the ticket, you can, but you will have to PHYSICALLY APPEAR in court which means you have to come back to TX to stand in long lines waiting for your case to be called - not fun and not a good decision. Judges ALWAYS side with the officer - don't let anyone tell you differently.

Personally, I would just pay it and be done with it - for future visits, get a rental car with a TX license plate. TX police pull over "out of state" license plates all the time because TX is a major throughway for illegal drugs, cartels, etc.

Also, statistics have shown that cops generally stop red cars more often than any other color (I don't know why so don't ask, lol), so get a silver or black rental car. I wish you the best. No matter what happens don't worry. It's not worth it to sacrifice personal happiness for such a matter.

Cheers!

Comment: Just wanted to comment to say I have lived in more places than TX and the police are the same EVERYWHERE - state police are the worst...The inner city police in smaller towns aren't as bad as the ones that patrol larger cities, etc. - Some food for thought. Don't waste your money on a lawyer either - Ive already been down that road. A 200 dollar ticket costed me more than double by the time the lawyer was done mucking everything up - so from personal experience, DONT HIRE A LAWYER - just pay the ticket and get it out of your life. No regrets.

Comment: Yet I have only ever had polite police when I have gotten pulled over in VA and WVa, so YMMV

Comment: I've only ever had police be polite to me, everywhere in the US.  On the other hand, I *strongly* suspect I'm above the 90th percentile as far as being polite to the police first goes.

Comment: I was pulled over by a sheriff in Texas once for going significantly over the speed limit. I've never had a cop be rude to me, but that one in particular was extraordinarily polite. It was hard to even be mad about the ticket. I was a young, white, reasonably attractive female though, so YMMV.

Comment: The red car thing is because it stands out. This is actually biological / evolutionary rather than just "oh you're in a sporty car". Many animals including humans are programmed to see red above many other colors. So if you want to avoid tickets get a good old boring beige car. The more you blend in the better.

Comment: @jcast You say that "the police are the same EVERYWHERE" but the examples you give seem to actually be within the USA. There are many places outside the USA that also have police.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Heh you go on, as if these places called not USA aren't fictional.

Comment: WRT the conduct of US law enforcement. I happend to have contact with police officers three times in the US (LAPD for "speeding" (kind of), CA State Trooper while wandering around a state beach in the middle of the night, and a county sheriff somewhere in CA too (another car bumped into my rental). In all occasions the officers where helpful and friendly. Just saying that *everywhere* and *everyone* does not seem to nail it.

Comment: Never been stopped in the US or outside, but have had dealing with US  and other LEOs on several occasions (never as a suspect though) and they were generally friendly, courteous, professional, individuals. I'm sure bad cops exist, but I'm even more sure that officers' stance towards people they encounter is very strongly dependent on how those people behave towards them (as is apparent from most if not all yt videos of 'bad cops', all of them I've seen start with a deliberately beligerent person baiting them). And of course everyone has a bad day once in a while, including cops.

Comment: @jwenting let me guess: white middle class male.

Comment: In the UK, red cars are allegedly stopped more frequently because the police are playing snooker: http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/422651.stm

Comment: American here. Parents probably got pulled over 5-10 times during my childhood while I was in the car. The cops (VA and some across the country on road trips) were always polite.

Comment: What I've found is that, if you want to fight, check the state's policy on a "right to a speedy trial"; sometimes the court date you're initially assigned for your "speedy trial" is a "stacked" date where the officer is scheduling several cases so he can deal with them in one go. **Waive** your right, and pick a different day of the week. I've gotten out of two tickets in CA doing this just because the cop didn't show up. A third ticket I got dismissed because the cop was irritable and ill-organized, and couldn't remember the details of the stop 3-4 months later.

Comment: @CcDd I'll vouch for that. I drive a plain white pickup with a toolbox, looks like any number of generic utility/maintenance fleet trucks (and is popular with the state highway crews as well). I've blown right past a state trooper doing 85 in a 65 and he was *leaning out the window with his radar gun*. Had a near heart attack, but as I watched in my rearview, he never even flinched until I saw some little sporty red thing following me up the left lane. Saw the lights go on, and the trooper only had eyes for the red car, zero interest in me.

Comment: @DoktorJ that is a good point changing it to a much later time and being organized can toss them out. and yep always drive around with a red car it's safer that way.

Comment: The myth about the red cars being stopped more than others could be down to the cops playing snooker... Maybe get a white car, nobody wants to pot a white!

Comment: I am a habitual speeder and I drive quite a bit, which means I get pulled **a lot** - at least twice a year. 90% of the cops I encounter are polite, and I'd say only one was truly rude. Though to be fair on that one, I brought it upon myself by being an idiot. And no, I'm not an attractive female.

Answer (score 20):

First IANAL, lets get that out of the way.

Next, what can you do to correct the situation. This gets a bit more complicated. Before you go wasting a ton of money on the situation there are some consideration to tackle.

Speeding tickets are considered a civil matter, and as such fall under a different set of rules (in TX they are apparently criminal). Most importantly you are considered guilty unless you can prove your not. Now to be honest this is not exactly true, but the courts will take, without hesitation, the ticket as proof that you were speeding. Your only real defense in this case is to try to prove that the cop was wrong. The courts won't like this. It's wasting their time.

Next, **YOU WERE SPEEDING!!!** Can't stress that enough. Ignorance of the law does not mean you do not have to follow it. Neither does the fact that you were "going with the flow".  700 people break the law and you get cought, you were still breaking the law. Traffic laws are even worse like that.

Unfortunately, it doesn't matter how rude the officer was. I will say that the experience is not typical (at least where I live), but then again, you don't know why he drew his gun.  I will say that all police I have ever seen will approach a car with extreme caution. Often times this means hands on their gun. They are even trained to touch your car in certain spots to make sure they leave finger prints in case you kill them.  It is a very dangerous time for a cop (approaching a car). For future reference, the best thing you can do is turn off your radio, place your hands on the steering wheel  and sit still, waiting for the cop to approach. DO NOT REACH FOR ANYTHING until asked. Remember here in the US we can all carry guns and the cops are trained to react to that. Mainly if they see you reach for a spot they can't see, they will react more defensively.

The final consideration is the cost. It's often times WAY cheaper to just pay the ticket. 9/10 times it's cheaper. Specially in your case where you were actually speeding.

**Final Advice**

Go to the website http://www.dmv.org/tx-texas/paying-traffic-tickets.php Pay the ticket online, by phone, or by mail. Plead "No contest" which means your not going to admit your guilty, but that your not going to fight it either, then pay the fine.

If you have to make a court appearance, you can usually do so by phone, but with something as simple as a speeding ticket, they will not likely want you to take up valuable court room time.

**As for the cop**

I'd say chalk it up to bad luck. I'm sure you did some things to put the cop in a more defensive stance then he really needed to be in, but at the same time, there's no reason he should have been rude either. Most of the cops around here (I don't live in TX though) are friendly and helpful, even if they still approach a car with extreme caution.

Comment: The cop was probably on edge due to some radio traffic.  It is likely that this person's vehicle and configuration was a close match to someone dangerous they were looking for.  I doubt this person did anything to spook him.

Comment: Note as with the previous answer, "DMV.org" is **NOT** a government website.

Comment: Ignorance of the law, and the road not being properly marked are not the same thing.

Comment: "Neither does the fact that you were "going with the flow"" - this actually depends on the state, and some of the other answers suggest that Texas is one in which it actually does matter. Of course, without being able to show up in court this defense isn't an option for OP.

Comment: We did *nothing* to put the cop in a more defensive stance. I would own it up if we did, but honestly we didn't. We didn't move, we stopped the car immediately. Also, I agree with the comment above. Ignorance of the law and no road marks are not the same thing. I'm not saying we weren't 'speeding', I'm just saying we didn't do it on *purpose*. What do you expect someone to do in a similar situation then? Drive 15-20 miles slower than the rest of the traffic in hope of finding a sign?

Comment: @coteyr Are you from Texas? In Texas, speeding tickets are generally a [class C misdemeanor](http://www.statutes.legis.state.tx.us/Docs/TN/htm/TN.542.htm#542.301), technically a criminal offense, albeit the most minor level there is. The exception would be if you were driving so fast as to be considered reckless, in which case the class might go up. If the OP were going to fight this in court, they could appeal to the [reasonable and prudent](http://www.statutes.legis.state.tx.us/Docs/TN/htm/TN.545.htm#545.351) clause of sections 545.351 and 545.352 of the Texas Transportation Code.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 Most states have a set speed for a road size. TX has Sec. 545.352.  PRIMA FACIE SPEED LIMITS.  http://www.statutes.legis.state.tx.us/Docs/TN/htm/TN.545.htm Your supposed to know these before you drive in a different state or country. That said, I would have done the same as you, maybe capping out at 75 (a common speed limit), got the ticket, then paid it.  As for "We did nothing to put the cop in a more defensive stance" It really doesn't need to be anything you did. There could have been a builtin for that style of car, or a car from CA. or any number of things...

Comment: still no excuse for the cop to be rude though. There is no reason for that.

Comment: If you remember the police department that issued the ticket, call and file a formal complaint, try to give as much detail as you can, even if you can't remember the cops name, they can probably work it out from the timestamp on the ticket. Unfortunately, this will probably result in no action being taken, but if this cop has a history and their boss is particularly civically minded, they may get a stern talking to and you may receive a verbal or written apology. Sadly there's no central complaints department unlike in many countries, so it's really hit and miss.

Comment: Counter argument: Going slower than everybody else is dangerous.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Perhaps it should but it doesnt.

Comment: @coteyr rude is relative to a degree. Maybe if I'd been the one stopped I've have found him brusque, to the point, rather than rude...

Comment: @Joshua that doesn't make speeding legal. And in some places there are lower speed limits as well as upper speed limits (something that IMO should be universal).

Comment: Ignorance of the law is no excuse but ignorant of codes, acts and statutes is imperative. You didn't break the law, who is the plaintiff? What have you done to them? No harm no foul. You have a right to question your accuser. Who is your accuser, the state? What, a piece of paper? Should have asked the officer if something is an order each time he asked you, then sent the station a bill for all fulfilled orders.

Comment: @jwenting Not so. In fact you can get a ticket for driving too slowly while driving the posted speed limit.

Comment: @Anon343224user the ticket is an order to show up in court, where the police officer will appear as the 'accuser'. You do not have a right to unilaterally charge fees for "fulfilled orders" or for anything at all, and only severely misguided people believe they do.

Comment: @Joshua if you can you're screwed either way... If you speed you get a ticket for that, if you don't you get a ticket for that. Any sensible court would throw out such a ticket and call the entire law in question. Of course deliberately causing a dangerous situation is something else, and going below the speed limit in the fast lane would count as such (but not driving at the limit in the slow lane).

Comment: @Random832 you have a right to move. The user was moving. The officer interfered with their right to move. You have a right to charge for orders. The officer receives orders at the station from the sergeant, carries out all the orders, gets paid at the end of the month. The officer gives orders to others, and isn't going to pay for what he orders?

Comment: @Anon343224user You are _deeply_ confused if you think that "order" as a lawful command to do something and an "order" as a request to buy a product are in any way related.

Comment: Keep paying your fines @Random832.

Answer (score 9):

Sorry to hear about your bad luck.  I apologize for your treatment, but keep in mind that once the citation is issued, the real matter is economic in nature--not who is right or wrong!

Even if you pay the fine, you can still file a complaint with the officer's department and your country's state department--but that is a separate matter from the citation/ticket.  e.g. even if you are 'speeder', you deserve to be treated with some level of respect and politeness.

You can also call your country's equivalent to the US's state department for guidance, but if you only want to make this 'go away' as fast as possible:

1. Call the courthouse clerk's number listed on the ticket (allowing time for the ticket to be processed by their system--usually 2-3 days)
2. Politely ask how much the fine is and where to mail the check
3. Explain that you don't have a US bank account and are a foreign national and don't live in the US.  (Consider their response to this)
4. Ask if they accept Credit Cards (Using a Credit card may incur an additional fee, but will prevent issues with monetary conversions and will close the matter immediately as far as your involvement)
5. Pay, and DONE.

Note that you can call multiple times... and the Clerk will be your primary resource for getting this taken care of... so be especially nice and they'll potentially be an ally.

That's the easy way.  Being 'right' is usually more expensive and time consuming, and won't really involve the officer that much--the whole traffic thing is quite a well-oiled-machine while you are in it.

Importantly, if you do not appear in traffic court on the date provided by the county clerk (even if you are not informed of the date because you do not call) there will be a warrant issued for your arrest.  That warrant will extend only to TX borders...  But once things progress that far, the fines and fees are usually much higher...  But you can usually request rescheduling of the date as needed, just make sure you confirm the date/times with the clerk.

Unless your fine is more than several hundred dollars, IMHO--engaging a lawyer is probably not going to be economical.  (If you were on a business trip, your company may have some 'legal insurance' that could offset costs and get you represented quickly though)

On the phone with the clerk, you may want to ask if you can get a jury trial... they may be able to close the matter there.  But getting the while mess resolved in the courts is going to take a lot of your time while just paying will close the matter quickly.

I know you feel angry and upset about this.  However, sometimes it is easier to just pay the extra driving tax and move on. Just bad luck really.

Comment: what are you apologizing for ?

Comment: @martinVegtar As a human being.

Answer (score 6):

I'd contact a lawyer in the jurisdiction that the infraction took place.  You don't need a really good one, just one that will look out for your interests.  If you have friends in the area perhaps they can recommend someone or post on the law side of stack exchange.

For probably less than a few hundred dollars you can get the ticket dismissed.  Maybe not, but the worst case is that you show you left the country a short time after the ticket was issued and you pay the fine.  This way you can return to the US without any fear.

Like any profession there are good and bad people in law enforcement.  Even the nice guys, when they discover you have a warrant, will probably pull a gun.  So you will want to make sure one does not exist for you.

My son is in law enforcement and I think he is pretty fair, but he can get cranky.  One time he pulled his gun on a deaf guy.  Why?  He pulled the deaf guy over, and the deaf guy gets out of the car as soon as he is stopped.  Policy says an officer must pull his gun in those circumstances.  In the end it was a cordial exchange and scary for both parties.  Picture it, a deaf guy waving his arms trying to communicate.  When he sees the gun, his natural reaction is to wave his arms more.  As the cop, all you see is some guy waving his arms coming at you!  Tense for both parties.

Add to this the rancor of this election.  This cop probably pictured some Hollywood hippies attempting to commit voter fraud in his county.  From your retelling of the story, I would bet that was in the back of his mind.

I am sorry you had a negative experience, but despite the press such kind of things are a minority of police interactions.

Comment: So your advice is to pay *a few hundred dollars* to a lawyer, instead of just paying the ticket (and pay a second time if you lose)? I fail to see the benefit.

Comment: Because of the possibility of a warrant.  He failed to appear in court and may have a warrant in his name which could prompt an arrest.  Its doubtful the OP would like to spend his next US holiday in jail.

Comment: Isn't it enough to just pay the fine?

Comment: From what the OP poster said, no.  However perhaps a check to the court would be prudent.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. If the ticket does not list the infraction, nor a price to pay, there is something strange going on (strange = corruption). Hiring a lawyer that has relationships can help clarify what the charges are, and what the penalties are.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev - OP says the ticket indicates they need to go to court and does not list an amount to pay. And, OP has not posted a copy of the ticket yet. It could be that the officer wrote the ticket for an offense that is serious enough to require an appearance in court. An attorney may increase the cost, but they can appear in court on your behalf, and they know the local law and procedures. So, depending on the ticket, this might be the best advice.

Answer (score 3):

If you decide to fight this (I'm not advising that, just considering the possibility that you might want to), your defense might hinge on the fact that you didn't see a sign showing a lower speed limit. The question then is whether there was a sign, and you didn't notice it, or there really wasn't a sign.

If there really wasn't a sign, the relevant "law" is contained in the US DOT [Manual of Uniform Traffic Control Devices](http://mutcd.fhwa.dot.gov/kno_2009r1r2.htm). Federal law mandates that the standards specified in the MUTCD apply to: "...all traffic control devices installed on any street, highway, bikeway, or private road open to public
travel...". To be complete, you'll probably want to cite the specific state and county laws (and if this was in a city, their laws as well) saying that they'll comply with the federal law mandating conformance with the MUTCD.

The requirement you care about is in Section 2B.13, paragraph 03 of the MUTCD:

> Speed Limit (R2-1) signs, indicating speed limits for which posting is required by law, shall be located at the points of change from one speed limit to another.

So, if the speed limit changed, and there really *wasn't* a speed limit sign to tell you about the change, then the state (or county, or whatever) is the one violating the law.

The one time in my life that I got a speeding ticket, I went to court and cited this requirement, and moved that the ticket be thrown out on this grounds alone.

Since the judge *really* didn't want to rule that the city was violating federal law, he decided to hold the trial, and only rule on my motion if I was found guilty. Although I actually had pretty solid evidence that I wasn't guilty, I'm pretty sure if all I'd done was say: "your honor, I'm *certain* I wasn't going that fast", he still would have decided that was good enough evidence, and found me not guilty.

This does all hinge on the basic question of whether there *really* wasn't a sign to tell you about the change in speed limit though. In my case there definitely wasn't. In your case...I don't know for sure, but if you want to take this approach, you'll need to verify one way or the other.

Answer (score 2):

In some states, paying a traffic fine is structured in a rather odd way: what you will do is post bail for your court appearance and then forfeit it by not showing up. That's the end, except for whatever the repercussions are with your home country insurance and driving privileges. (Unless you are Canadian these are almost certainly zero.)

California also allows you to post bail and request a trial by written declaration. I have no idea if Texas allows this. If you were to contest the ticket, I do not think a defense of "Everyone else was going 75" is likely to help. However, a defense that there is no speed limit sign between where you entered the freeway and where you were ticketed might work, especially as 60 is below the standard limit for a Texas freeway.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of suggestions here on how to pay or fight the ticket. That would be the right thing to do if you want to be *absolutely* certain that this ticket never comes back to bother you.

You might be able to just ignore it, though, if you're feeling brave or lucky. (Note that I'm not a lawyer, and I'm clearly not responsible for any trouble you get in if you do choose to ignore it.)

They're not going to contact your government over a speeding ticket, or send somebody to track you down, so there's no way it's an issue until you come back to the states.

States generally don't worry about traffic tickets in other states, so it's not an issue until you come back to Texas specifically.

Even if you come back to Texas, it's not an issue unless you get pulled over again.

Even then, the cop has to notice the ticket and care. You could always fight it at that point, if necessary.

For a little support, note that I lived in Texas for over a year, and much of my family lives in Texas. Although I don't think I've ever ignored a speeding ticket, I've ignored plenty of automated tolls I was unaware of before getting on the road, or questionable parking tickets, and never had a problem.

Of course, depending on the size of the fine associated with the ticket, they may be more interested in pursuing it than they would be for a simple parking ticket.

As for whether your experience was typical, I would say not. Cops are people. Just like other people, some are assholes, most aren't. Note that some police are a bit biased, and may become tense and react differently if you appear a certain way. This is especially true if you have darker skin, or anything that makes you look like a stereotypical criminal, which could include things like long hair or tattoos.

Answer (score 1):

Guns in the US are normal, they're not something that you only see in movies. I got stopped for speeding once in Colorado and had a similar experience (except that the guy was a bit quicker to grasp that I was a foreigner and not familiar with local customs). But however weird it might seem to Europeans, Americans are allowed to carry guns and the police have to assume that a car driver stopped for speeding might use one if given the chance. So any contact with the police is going to seem confrontational.

Answer (score -1):

Do you plan on coming back to the US? If not, then don't sweat it. Texas isn't going to ask to have your country return you to the US for a traffic citation. Unless you plan to return, then ignore it. If you do plan to return, pay the fine to avoid hassles in the future when you return. Bench warrants don't disappear and any future interactions with police in the US will likely result in your incarceration while you get that old ticket/warrant sorted out. It'll cost a pretty penny too.

As to the rudeness of the cop, welcome to the US. Cops are a'hole's and love to pull their guns and shout at people. They get off on it. The only thing they like better is to shoot your dog, or you if they think they can get away with it. A lot of real sicko's in the police in this country. And they wonder why we don't like them...

Answer (score -3):

This is what I would do. Most courts allow you to ask them to waive things by mail. Use google maps street view to show there was no speed limit signs between the offramp and the spot you were stopped. Also explain you are out of the country and would like to move the case to x country as physically getting to a texas courthouse would be expensive difficult and time consuming (this should get the point across that you are unable to go to the local court). You would like them to give you video from the officer's car and any body cams he had due to threatening you and his discrimination against you so you can build a case against the police department.

You may get the ticket dismissed especially if they think they will lose. Adding the bit about the dashcam and body cam with the drawn weapon and feeling threatened might be enough to get them to drop it.

Unfortunately this is pretty typical everywhere in republican counties. please don't drop your money there again and instead come to california. Our cops are way more civil ;)

If they do not drop it make sure you get the body cam footage and build a case it may net you a good $20k+ depending on how noisy you are with it. Post them online ask for funding through go fund me type sites etc.

---

ok so some are confused by my suggestions. Please note if you do not want to fight it then simply paying it is hassle free ish. but if you want to fight it then:

In the letter show there were no speed limit signs between the off ramp and where you were stopped by using google street view. Ask them for the officer's body cam and dash cam video of the incident stating you were targeted as a foreigner and the officer had his gun drawn and was yelling something about if you were from California for some reason. You would also like to know when his radar gun was calibrated last and also how he determined you were driving at the speed you were driving. Ask for a change of venue to your country (this will get denied of course but it will also get their attention).

You can also send a letter to any foreign consulates there about this incident and possibly the local government as well.

you can also mention you are looking into going after the police department for their unprofessional behavior. and once you get the videos, might take a few phone calls, you can then post them on travel websites.

---

Apparently I am horrible at explaining things so here's another go.

Use google maps to show no signs. Get their attention asking for a change of venue. Show them you are willing to fight by asking for videos and other data to build your case. Put some extra pressure on them by contacting the consulate and the local government offices there. This shows a mix of things primarily your ticked and will try to go after them, you're not planning to pay and they can't make you, and lastly you may end up embarrassing them, causing a minor international issue, or reducing vacation revenue.

Most importantly show them you may have a case against them due to the pointing the gun, threatening you, and targeting you because you are a foreigner. You may be able to add in the innate bias against california as well.

Comment: "Move the case to x country?" I have truly never heard of a procedure where a speeding ticket can be handled in another country! How would that even work?

Comment: @ZachLipton I don't think one exists but that line would be used more to get someone's attention rather than to actually get it moved. I would say it's about making a point in the letter they will write.

Comment: +1 for "don't drop your money there again and instead come to California". I'd pay the ticket to avoid future legal issues, but write to the local chamber of commerce and tourist promotion authorities offering them a chance to make amends before you spam your experience as far and wide as you are able on the internet. Of course it's possible that this county doesn't want tourists!

Comment: @CcDd What would that point be? Trying to look stupid by saying something nonsensical?

Comment: @svick incorrect it is to get their attention and make a point.

Comment: @Thomas why wouldn't I?

Comment: this is really weird advice

Comment: @galois I will update my answer with the reasons this works.

Comment: You had me with "Use google maps street view ...", but then you immediately lost me with everything following that.

Comment: @KevinFegan ok not quite sure how to explain it more directly but here it goes. Use google maps to show no signs. Get their attention asking for a change of venue. Show them you are willing to fight by asking for videos and other data to build your case. Put some extra pressure on them by contacting the consulate and the local government offices there. This shows a mix of things primarily your ticked and will try to go after them, you're not planning to pay and they can't make you, and lastly you may end up embarrassing them, causing a minor international issue, or reducing vacation revenue.

Comment: Your last comment at least clarifies what you were thinking with this answer.  However, the *actual* result, as @svick alludes to, would be that you would come across as confused and utterly incoherent, and that you would end up with *more* problems, not less.

Comment: @Wildcard I would argue it depends on how you write it. If you do it at 2am like I did there isn't a good chance it will have the effect you want.